# Ansible set_fact and if in loop does not work?

Tags: ansible

Here is my playbook :

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    myvar: "none"

  tasks:

    - name: set new value
      set_fact:
        myvar: "{% if myvar == 'none' %}{{ item }}{% endif %}"
      loop:
        - aaa
        - bbb
        - ccc

    - name : print myvar
      debug:
        msg: "myvar is {{ myvar }}"
```

And its result :

```yaml
TASK [set new value] *******************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=aaa)
ok: [localhost] => (item=bbb)
ok: [localhost] => (item=ccc)

TASK [print myvar] *********************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "myvar is "
}
```

So why `myvar` is not `"aaa"` ?

And how to change my test to give the right value without using the `when:` clause, i.e just with `if`?

PS: I had this sentence to tell Stackoverflow that my question is not mostly code and to see my question accepted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be an error in the logic implemented. The following example will show this.

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    myvar: "none"

  tasks:

  - name: Show new value
    debug:
      msg: "{% if myvar == 'none' %}{{ item }}{% endif %}"
    loop:
      - first
      - second

  - name: Set new value
    set_fact:
      myvar: "{% if myvar == 'none' %}{{ item }}{% else %}not none{% endif %}"
    loop:
      - first
      - second

  - name: Show new value
    debug:
      msg: "myvar was {{ myvar }}"
```

Whereby just printing out the value will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Show new value] *************
ok: [localhost] => (item=first) =>
  msg: first
ok: [localhost] => (item=second) =>
  msg: second
```

setting value with that approach will not and resulting into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Set new value] ***********
ok: [localhost] => (item=first)
ok: [localhost] => (item=second)

TASK [Show new value] **********
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: myvar was not none
```

This is because during the second run the value of `myvar` is already `first`, not `none` and therefore the condition `{% if myvar == 'none' %}` can't come in place. See

```yaml
  - name: Set new value
    set_fact:
      myvar: "{% if myvar == 'none' %}{{ item }}{% else %}not none{% endif %}"
    loop:
      - first

  - name: Show new value
    debug:
      msg: "myvar was {{ myvar }}"
```

as it will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Set new value] **********
ok: [localhost] => (item=first)

TASK [Show new value] *********
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: myvar was first
```

To summarize

> *Ansible `set_fact` and `if` in `loop` does not work*

does work as expected and

> *So why `myvar` is not `aaa` ?*

because the condition was not met.

> *How to change my test to give the right value without using the `when` clause, i.e just with `if`?*

Even if it is not clear for me what you try to achieve introducing an `{% else %}` might help.

`{% if myvar == 'none' %}{{ item }}{% else %}not none{% endif %}`